# Why is a finite field finite dimensional over $\mathbb F_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields, intuition

I am trying to understand why a finite field is finite dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$.

I know that if $\mathbb F$ has $p^n$ elements, then $\dim(\mathbb F)=n$. But why is this so?

Certainly $\mathbb R$ is not finite but $\mathbb R^n$ is also finite dimensional.

Comment: Any vector space which is infinite dimensional contains vector spaces of every finite dimension. So a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$ which is not finite dimensional has more than $p^n$ elements for each $n$.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Surely the elements of the field span the field as a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$, yes?  That already means it is finite dimensional.

Comment: Consider the fact ${\mathbb{F}_{{p^n}}} \cong \frac{{{\mathbb{F}_p}\left[ x \right]}}{{\left\langle {f\left( x \right)} \right\rangle }}$ for some irreducible,monic polynomial $f$ of degree n.

Comment: Did you show a field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ with $p^n$ elements is a $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ vector space ?

Answer (score 3):

Because an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ has infinitely many elements. Since it is infinite-dimensional, it has a countable subset $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}$ which is linearly independent.

On the other hand, if $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ are $k$ linearly independent elements of $\mathbb F$, then the elements of $\mathbb F$ of the form $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_kv_k$ are $p^k$ distinct elements of $\mathbb F$. Since $\mathbb F$ has $p^n$ elements and since it must have a basis as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$, such a basis must have $n$ elements, and therefore $\mathbb F$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$.